# How much storage space will be sufficient for installing Windows 10 in case Windows is my second OS? First is Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I want to install another OS Windows10 on my machine. I already have Ubuntu 20.04 on my machine and Windows10 will be the second one. So, I don't have any idea that how much partition space should I give to Windows10 so, in the future, I don't face any problem related to storage. I have 1 TB Hard Disk space free and 240 GB SSD space. My Ubuntu is in SSD and I want to install Windows10 too on SSD. So, please suggest, how much space should I dedicate to Windows10.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+10+minimum+requirements

Comment: Other than what is specified by Microsoft themselves you will need a good amount of space free for feature updates and programs in general. How much you have is up to you.